# .net unit testing - How to test Insert/Update/Delete methods

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I am using .net unit testing in my project. I can unit test, get methods by using Assert.AreEqual. But how can i test Insert/update/delete methods. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For insert, the basic test pattern could be:

- create entity instance
- insert entity
- read inserted entity
- compare created entity and read entity
- delete entity

For update:

- create entity instance
- insert entity
- change entity properties
- update entity
- read updated entity
- compare changed entity and read entity
- delete entity

For delete:

- create entity instance
- insert entity
- delete entity
- read deleted entity (should fail)

Note than in order to compare reference entities, you can do it manually for each entity type or use a recursive entity comparison method

Answer (score 2):

To test the insert, you insert a record from your test, then get the record in the same test and then user `Assert.AreEqual` to assert that what you got is what you had inserted. You can use to the primary/unique key of the record to get the records in this case.

Similar would be update. You update the record from test, then get the updated record and assert that the values you got are updated values.

For delete, you delete the record from test and then get the record. Here you can assert that get does not actually return anything